# Visual Studio running wrong form class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 express (using vb.net) I've somehow set two forms to use the same class.

Basicly I have two designer files with 1 implementation each. For some reason both designer files are calling the same implementation file, and I can't find any settings to correct the problem. Help!

Comment: This question makes very little sense. What do you mean the access the same code? YOu mean the same designer file? Or two designer files access the same implementation file? I dont think you will get many answers until you can clear this up a bit, try to explain more

Comment: @musefan thanks for the right terminology

Comment: The "designer" file term is right, the "implementation" I guessed at, never heard it have a name before (maybe code behind applies here too) but either way your question makes more sense now - sorry I dont know the answer though

Comment: When you say "designer" files, do you mean `Form1.vb` or `Form1.Designer.vb`? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "calling".